# QTableWidget not displaying text

Tags: qt

I am building a simple widget that will take an input from a lineEdit, and add it as a new row (assuming that the entry is not in there already) to a QTableWidget. The problem I have been encountering is that the text will not display in the tablewidget, though the rows appear--empty.

Relevant code:

In constructor:

```
rowCounter = 0;
ui->flagTable->setColumnCount(1);
ui->flagTable->horizontalHeader()->hide();
ui->flagTable->verticalHeader()->hide();
ui->flagTable->setColumnWidth(0,148);
QString commandInput = ui->flagInput->text();
```

In on_flagInput_returnPressed():

```
QString commandInput = ui->flagInput->text();
if (ui->flagTable->findItems(commandInput, Qt::MatchFixedString).isEmpty())
{
    rowCounter++;
    ui->flagTable->setRowCount(rowCounter);
    ui->flagTable->setItem(rowCounter, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(commandInput));
```

}

^ that's in the code.

Comment: You have a memory leak, as `commandItem` is never used or deleted. Maybe you meant to use it instead of `new QTableWidgetItem(commandInput)`? Also, why are you setting it at column 1, while your flagTable only has 1 column? Shouldn't this be 0?

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind That was left over from a previous attempt. Reformatted, same bug persists

Comment: You are also setting the item on `rowCount()`, not `rowCount() - 1`. Do you see the previous input when adding a new unique input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

Initialized rowCounter with a value of zero, so it was always setting the item to a row that hadn't been initialized yet!

Here's the working version if anyone encounters the same issue:

Constructor:

```
rowCounter = 1;
ui->flagTable->setColumnCount(1);
ui->flagTable->horizontalHeader()->hide();
ui->flagTable->verticalHeader()->hide();
ui->flagTable->setColumnWidth(0,148);
```

on_flagInput_returnPressed():

```
QString commandInput = ui->flagInput->text();
if (ui->flagTable->findItems(commandInput, Qt::MatchFixedString).isEmpty())
{
    QTableWidgetItem *commandItem = new QTableWidgetItem(commandInput, 1);
    ui->flagTable->setRowCount(rowCounter);
    ui->flagTable->setItem(rowCounter-1, 0, commandItem);
    rowCounter++;
}
```